# ACF - repeater only showing 1 row on blog page

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have a repeater in my `footer.php` file and it works for the entire website, but whenever I go to the blog page (`index.php`), the repeater only displays *one row* of the entire repeater and I don't know why this is happening.

I've tried putting `get_option('page_for_posts')` as the repeater field's second parameter, but this didn't work.

This is how it looks on every page except the blog page.

[image]

and this is how it looks on the blog page itself:

[image]

It only shows one row on the blog page, which is the *About Us* column.

Here's the code:

```
<?php if ( have_rows('post_object_repeater') ) : ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('post_object_repeater') ) : the_row(); ?>
        <?php $header = get_sub_field( 'header' ); ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $number_of_columns; ?> col-md-6 col-12 list-column">
            <?php

            $posts = get_sub_field('post_object_relationship');

            if( $posts ): ?>
                <ul class="list-unstyled <?php if ( ! $header ): echo 'no-header'; endif; ?>">
                    <?php if ( $header ): ?>
                        <li class="header mb-3 font-weight-bold text-uppercase"><?php echo $header; ?></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php foreach( $posts as $post): ?>
                        <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
                        <li class="list-item">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This repeater does have a relationship field inside to pull each of the individual pages or custom post types of the website. Would anyone have an idea why not all of the repeater rows display on a blog page, but work on all other pages?

Comment: Is the repeater 'post_object_repeater' meta box on an option page or each individual page?

Comment: The repeater is in an ACF option page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
if(have_rows('post_object_repeater', 'option')

while(have_rows('post_object_repeater', 'option'))
```

etc.

????

Comment: This was the solution! Thank you.